# Tableau Regex Issue : Regular Expression Regexp_replace() is not showing any Replace for "\U\1\E" Pattern

Tags: regex, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I wrote a regular expression in the hope that I would be able to replace every match (that is just one character) with an uppercase character. This is a very long text file, more like a feedback and flight delay description. This would take a very long time to do by hand, and mostly it comes from a Qualtrics tool, so we can't change it through the backend.

It would be quite complicated to do without regular expressions because current examples that are floating right now have performance issues, which I definitely would like to avoid.

**Current Solution 01:** [Delay Desc Ref] is my current Field

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(

REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(

REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(

REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(

REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(

REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(

REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(

[Delay Desc Ref]

,'(?<=^|\s)a','A'),'(?<=^|\s)b','B'),'(?<=^|\s)c','C'),'(?<=^|\s)d','D')

,'(?<=^|\s)e','E'),'(?<=^|\s)f','F'),'(?<=^|\s)g','G'),'(?<=^|\s)h','H')

,'(?<=^|\s)i','I'),'(?<=^|\s)j','J'),'(?<=^|\s)k','K'),'(?<=^|\s)l','L')

,'(?<=^|\s)m','M'),'(?<=^|\s)n','N'),'(?<=^|\s)o','O'),'(?<=^|\s)p','P')

,'(?<=^|\s)q','Q'),'(?<=^|\s)r','R'),'(?<=^|\s)s','S'),'(?<=^|\s)t','T')

,'(?<=^|\s)u','U'),'(?<=^|\s)v','V'),'(?<=^|\s)w','W'),'(?<=^|\s)x','X')

,'(?<=^|\s)y','Y'),'(?<=^|\s)z','Z')
```

**Solution 02:**

```
TRIM(

upper(left(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 1),1)) + lower(right(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 1),(len(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 1))-1))) + " "

+

IFNULL(upper(left(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 2),1)),"") + ifnull(lower(right(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 2),(len(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 2))-1))),"")

+ " " +

IFNULL(upper(left(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 3),1)),"") + ifnull(lower(right(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 3),(len(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 3))-1))),"")


+ " " +

IFNULL(upper(left(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 4),1)),"") + ifnull(lower(right(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 4),(len(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 4))-1))),"")


+ " " +

IFNULL(upper(left(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 5),1)),"") + ifnull(lower(right(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 5),(len(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 5))-1))),"")


+ " " +

IFNULL(upper(left(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 6),1)),"") + ifnull(lower(right(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 6),(len(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 6))-1))),"")

+ " " +

IFNULL(upper(left(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 7),1)),"") + ifnull(lower(right(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 7),(len(SPLIT([Delay Desc Ref], " ", 7))-1))),"")

)
```

All the above mentioned codes are working fine, but there is some performance issue, so I was trying to solve the issue using regular expressions.

**Performance Issue Image using workbook optimiser**

[image: Tableau Workbook optimiser Window]

I was able to generate the desired outcome using regex . Please refer to the below image
[image: Capitalize the first letter in every word using Regex]

But the same logic does not work when using the "Regexp_Replace" function. I tried using both Live and Extract Connection . I am attaching the screenshot for your reference.

**Actual Tableau Expression :** REGEXP_REPLACE([Delay Desc Ref],"\b(\w)","\U\1\E")

[image: Tableau Regex Replace is not working as expected]

Example :

**Delay Desc Ref Attributes**

aircraft defects
aircraft rotation
airport facilities baggage
processing ciq (customs, immigration & quarantine)
clearance /sequencing for arrival
clearance en-route (atfm)

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong and how I can achieve the same within Tableau.

> Search: \b(\w)
>
> Replace by: \U\1\E

Comment: First things first, did you try `REGEXP_REPLACE([Delay Desc Ref],"\\b(\\w)","\\U\\1\\E")`?

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor, for your response.Yes I did try that but no luck at all.

Comment: Then why at all try this? The [docs](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_additional.htm) say "For Tableau extracts, regular expression syntax conforms to the standards of the current **International Components for Unicode (ICU)**", ICU regex library does not support `\U` and `\L` case changing operators in the replacement.

Comment: If I dont use this Regex, then the performance of the workbook is going for a toss. Any alternative which you can suggest